# Listing files with ls -R no subdir info

Tags: linux, ls

I want to list recursively files but without the directory information, so to be the exactly the same format as normal ls -la.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -name '*' -exec ls -la {} \; | sed '/^total/d'
```

Comment: this works fine but, it also prints the "total number" for every file and i really want only the files listed with privileges without any gaps.

Comment: I have added sed to the answer.

Comment: well i tried to achieve my goal without using regexp in fact i wondered if ls itself contains options to do this, but your answer undoubtedly works.

Comment: actually easier way to do this is by find . -name '*' -printf '%M\n'

Comment: or rather find . -name '*' -printf '%p\n' :-) ?